# How to do Cognito authentication in lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito

Any one could you please assist me that how to create the Lambda function for "Sign In using Cognito".

Is that possible in server side OR only possible in client side?

I have searched in the below link, But we don't know which one Should I use it for SignIn.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. Is this helpful: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

Comment: I can't tell if you're 1) trying to lo get Cognito to use your Lambda function to tell if somebody should be authenticated or 2) trying to authenticate a given username & password in a Lambda function using Cognito.

#1 is not possible, #2 is easy.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible by using the node version of the Cognito Javascript SDK.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js-node